# Should SRP always be respected?

Tags: c#, single-responsibility-principle

I'm having a hard time understanding if it is sometimes acceptable to break the Single Responsibility Principle, or if it should be avoided at all cost.

Please note that the following code has been simplified to only keep the relevant part.

I have `Hero` class, that represent a Character, it can posses multiples different `Items`.
I have multiples class that inherit from `Items`, for example `QuestItems` and `BackpackItems`.
When I want to add an `Item` on my `Hero`, depending on the kind of `Item` I should act differently.
I've tried 2 different way to do that the first one respect the SRP :

```
 public abstract class Item
{
    private string _Name{get;set;}

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        protected set
        {
            if (_Name != value)
            {
                _Name = value;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class QuestItem: Item
{
    public QuestItem(String name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class BackpackItem: Item
{
    public BackpackItem(String name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
public class Hero
{
   public void AddItem(Item item){
      if(item is QuestItem){
         //Do stuff to add QuestItem
         return;
      }
      if(item is BackpackItem){
         //Do stuff to add BackpackItem
         return;
      }
   }
}
```

Advantages : SRP is respected
Disadvantage : if I create a new item kind inheriting from `Item` and forget to change my `AddItem` function in `Hero` I risk a lot of trouble.

My second solution that doesn't respect SRP :
my AddItem function become

```
public void AddItem(Item item){
          item.AddToHero(this);
       }
```

my Items class become :

```
 public abstract class Item
{
    private string _Name{get;set;}

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        protected set
        {
            if (_Name != value)
            {
                _Name = value;
            }
        }
    }
  public abstract void AddToHero(Hero hero);
}

public class QuestItem: Item
{
    public QuestItem(String name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public override void AddToHero(Hero hero)
    {
       //Do my stuff to add my QuestItem to Hero
    }
}

public class BackpackItem: Item
{
    public BackpackItem(String name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public override void AddToHero(Hero hero)
    {
       //Do my stuff to add my BackpackItem to Hero
    }
}
```

Advantage : I can't forget the add method from a new Item kind, as I will have an error at compile time.
Disadvantage : I don't respect SRP, but I for now don't really understand why it would be so bad.

What implementation should I prefer to use ? (another one ?)

Comment: Are you just interested in SRP, or all of SOLID? Because in the first example the Hero.AddItem method breaks the Open/Close principle.

Comment: I'm interested on how to learn/apply the best practise in order to improve my quality of code.
So any thing I should/could change really.

Answer (score 2):

Well, can only Heros "have" items in the repository? Aren't there locations, non-hero characters (maybe monsters) etc. who can also own items?

Since you mention that this is simplified, it's difficult to give a definitive answer to what the right approach is. Maybe neither is.

To me this kind of questions is not so much about SRP but rather about how generic something should be, and balancing that against KISS. For instance, it *may* be a better solution to uncouple Items and Heros altogether and instead have rules of interaction which determine what object can be used in what way be which hero or character. Because the next problem you may face is that you have different types of Heros, maybe a Wizard and a Warrior, who cannot do the same things with the same items.

Also, keep in mind that OOP (single) inheritance often does not map well to real-world situations; consider using a more compositional model instead.

Comment: Thank you for your input.
For now my `Heros` are the only ones that can interact with `Items`.
The entire code is available here : https://github.com/Belterius/LDVELH/tree/ViewModel/LDVELH_WPF but I don't think it will be of much use to give a quick help.
Do you have a link to an example/tutorial of a "more compositional model" ? So far I've only been exposed to OOP type of project.

Comment: @Belterius Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance for a start. Also worth a read: https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/ (and following blog posts)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, SRP is easily mentioned and quoted, but very often **hard** to follow in reality. Just figuring "what is **one** requirement" (that should go into one class) can be hard.

In your case, one alternative could be to move the responsibility of adding an Item to some Hero (or Monster or Whatever!) into its own class. Meaning: sometimes it makes sense to create a **Service** class that implements a specific piece of behavior that affects other classes A, B, C, ... but that really doesn't fit into any of A, B, C, ...

You know, not all classes need to reflect "objects". They can also represent "behavior"! So consider if some *ItemAdderService* would help you!

Comment: Do you mean implementing an interface that would take care of the "adding" part ?

Comment: Ideally an interface ;to allow for different implementations!